# Get data from a huge text file to replace data in another huge text file, efficiently (Python)

Tags: python, performance, text, replace, large-files

I've been programming for a couple of months, so I'm not an expert. I have two huge text files (omni, ~20 GB, ~2.5M lines; dbSNP, ~10 GB, ~60M lines). They have the first few lines, not necessarily tab-delimited, starting with "#" (the header) and the rest of the lines are organized in tab-delimited columns (the actual data).

The first two columns of each line contain the chromosome number and the position on the chromosome, while the third column contains an identification code. In the "omni" file I don't have the ID, so I need to find the position in the dbSNP file (a database) and create a copy of the first file completed with the IDs.

Because of memory limits I decided to read the two files line by line and restart from the last line read. I am not satisfied of the efficiency of my code, because I feel it is slower than it could be. I'm pretty sure that it is my fault, because of lack of experience. Is there a way to make it faster using Python? May the problem be the opening and closing of the files?

I usually launch the script in GNOME Terminal (Python 2.7.6, Ubuntu 14.04) like this:

> python -u Replace_ID.py > Replace.log 2> Replace.err

Thank you very much in advance.

omni ([Omni example](http://lucabetti.altervista.org/file/Omni_example.vcf)):

> ...
>   #CHROM   POS ID  REF ALT ...
>   1  534247 .   C   T ...
>   ...

dbSNP ([dbSNP example](http://lucabetti.altervista.org/file/dbSNP_example.vcf)):

> ...
>   #CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT ...
>   1       10019   rs376643643     TA      T ...
>   ...

The output should be exactly the same as the Omni file, but with the rs ID after the position.

Code:

```
SNPline = 0    #line in dbSNP file
SNPline2 = 0    #temporary copy
omniline = 0    #line in omni file
line_offset = []    #beginnings of every line in dbSNP file (stackoverflow.com/a/620492)
offset = 0
with open("dbSNP_build_141.vcf") as dbSNP: #database
    for line in dbSNP:
        line_offset.append(offset)
        offset += len(line)
    dbSNP.seek(0)
with open("Omni_replaced.vcf", "w") as outfile:     
    outfile.write("")       
with open("Omni25_genotypes_2141_samples.b37.v2.vcf") as omni:  
    for line in omni:           
        omniline += 1
        print str(omniline) #log
        if line[0] == "#":      #if line is header
            with open("Omni_replaced.vcf", "a") as outfile:
                outfile.write(line) #write as it is
        else:
            split_omni = line.split('\t') #tab-delimited columns
            with open("dbSNP_build_141.vcf") as dbSNP:
                SNPline2 = SNPline          #restart from last line found
                dbSNP.seek(line_offset[SNPline])    
                for line in dbSNP:
                    SNPline2 = SNPline2 + 1 
                    split_dbSNP = line.split('\t')  
                    if line[0] == "#":
                        print str(omniline) + "#" + str(SNPline2) #keep track of what's happening.
                        rs_found = 0    #it does not contain the rs ID
                    else:
                        if split_omni[0] + split_omni[1] == split_dbSNP[0] + split_dbSNP[1]:    #if chromosome and position match
                            print str(omniline) + "." + str(SNPline2) #log
                            SNPline = SNPline2 - 1
                            with open("Omni_replaced.vcf", "a") as outfile:
                                split_omni[2] = split_dbSNP[2]  #replace the ID
                                outfile.write("\t".join(split_omni)) 
                            rs_found = 1    #ID found
                            break        
                        else:
                            rs_found = 0    #ID not found
                if rs_found == 0:   #if ID was not found in dbSNP, then:
                    with open("Omni_replaced.vcf", "a") as outfile:
                        outfile.write("\t".join(split_omni)) #keep the line unedited
                else:   #if ID was found:
                    pass    #no need to do anything, line already written
    print "End."
```

Comment: Could you please provide more information to allow testing? For example provide 5 lines for each files and a 5 lines output that show the replacement process done? It will probably allow a better understanding of the code you provide, and also, will allow to test some modifications and verify consistency.

Comment: @ArthurVaïsse Thank you for your suggestion. I edited the original message. I could only add two links, so here is the Output file example: lucabetti.altervista.org/file/Output_example.vcf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my contribution to your problem. 
First of all, here is what I understand about your problem, just to check I'm correct :
You have two files, each are tabulation separated values file. The first, dbSNP, contains data, whose the third columns are identifiers corresponding to the gene's chromosome number (column 1) and the gene's position on the chromosome (column 2).

The task so consist of taking the omni file and filling in the ID column with all the values coming from the dbNSP file (based on the chromosome number and the gene position).

Problem come from the size of the files.
You tried to retain in the file position of each line to make seek and go directly to the good line in order to avoid tu put all the dbnsp file in memory. As this approach is not enough quick for you due to multiple file opening, here is what I propose.

Parse the dbNSP file one time to retain only the essential information, i.e. the couples `(number,position):ID`.
From your example that correspond to :

```
1   534247  rs201475892
1   569624  rs6594035
1   689186  rs374789455
```

This correspond to less than 10% of the file size in term of memory, so starting from a 20GB file you will load in memory less than 2GB, it is probably affordable(don't know what sort of loading you tried before).

So here is my code to do this. Do not hesitate to ask for explanation as unlike you, I use Object Programming.

```
import argparse

#description of this script
__description__ = "This script parse a Database file in order to find the genes identifiers and provide them to a other file.[description to correct]\nTake the IDs from databaseFile and output the targetFile content enriched with IDs"

# -*- -*-  -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- 
#classes used to handle and operate on data
class ChromosomeIdentifierIndex():
    def __init__(self):
        self.chromosomes = {}

    def register(self, chromosomeNumber, positionOnChromosome, identifier):
        if not chromosomeNumber in self.chromosomes:
            self.chromosomes[chromosomeNumber] = {}

        self.chromosomes[chromosomeNumber][positionOnChromosome] = identifier

    def __setitem__(self, ref, ID):
        """ Allows to use alternative syntax to chrsIndex.register(number, position, id) : chrsIndex[number, position] = id """
        chromosomeNumber, positionOnChromosome = ref[0],ref[1]
        self.register(chromosomeNumber, positionOnChromosome, ID)

    def __getitem__(self, ref):
        """ Allows to get IDs using the syntax: chromosomeIDindex[chromosomenumber,positionOnChromosome] """
        chromosomeNumber, positionOnChromosome = ref[0],ref[1]
        try:
            return self.chromosomes[chromosomeNumber][positionOnChromosome]
        except:
            return "."

    def __repr__(self):
        for chrs in self.chromosomes.keys():
            print "Chromosome : ", chrs
            for position in self.chromosomes[chrs].keys():
                print "\t", position, "\t", self.chromosomes[chrs][position]

class Chromosome():
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.values   = string.split("\t")
        self.chrs     = self.values[0]
        self.position = self.values[1]
        self.ID       = self.values[2]

    def __str__(self):
        return "\t".join(self.values)

    def setID(self, ID):
        self.ID = ID
        self.values[2] = ID

class DefaultWritter():
    """ Use to print if no output is specified """
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def write(self, string):
        print string
    def close(self):
        pass

# -*- -*-  -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- 
#The code executed when the scrip is called
if __name__ == "__main__":

    #initialisation
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = __description__)
    parser.add_argument("databaseFile"  , help="A batch file that contains many informations, including the IDs.")
    parser.add_argument("targetFile"    , help="A file that contains informations, but miss the IDs.")
    parser.add_argument("-o", "--output", help="The output file of the script. If no output is specified, the output will be printed on the screen.")
    parser.add_argument("-l", "--logs"  , help="The log file of the script. If no log file is specified, the logs will be printed on the screen.")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    output = None
    if args.output == None:
        output = DefaultWritter()
    else:
        output = open(args.output, 'w')

    logger = None
    if args.logs == None:
        logger = DefaultWritter()
    else:
        logger = open(args.logs, 'w')

    #start of the process

    idIndex = ChromosomeIdentifierIndex()

    #build index by reading the database file.
    with open(args.databaseFile, 'r') as database:
        for line in database:
            if not line.startswith("#"):
                chromosome = Chromosome(line)
                idIndex[chromosome.chrs, chromosome.position] = chromosome.ID

    #read the target, replace the ID and output the result
    with open(args.targetFile, 'r') as target:
        for line in target:
            if not line.startswith("#"):
                chromosome = Chromosome(line)
                chromosome.setID(idIndex[chromosome.chrs, chromosome.position])
                output.write(str(chromosome))
            else:
                output.write(line)

    output.close()
    logger.close()
```

The main idea is parsing the dbNSP file one time and collecting all the IDs in a dictionary. Then reading line by line the omnifile and outputting the result.

You can call the script like this :

```
python replace.py ./dbSNP_example.vcf ./Omni_example.vcf -o output.vcf
```

The argparse module I used and import to handle parameter also furnish auto-help, so description of parameter is available with

```
python replace.py -h
```

or

```
python replace.py --help
```

I believe that his approach will be faster than yours as I read file once and just work on RAM later, and I invite you to test it.

NB : I don't know if you are familiar to Object programing so I have to mention that here all the classes are in a same file for the sake of posting on stack overflow. In real life use case, good practice would be to put all the class in separate file like "Chromosome.py", "ChromosomeIdentifierIndex.py" and "DefaultWritter.py" for example, and then, import them into the "replace.py" file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tested it and it is actually a lot faster. I also learned a lot about Object programming in Python, and that's the most important thing. Bye